# how can i parse dynamic json data in obj-c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, parsing, dynamic

My json data could have any number of objects from a database.  This all comes in fine and sends the number to objective-c in gameCount.  From there I want the objectForKey to loop until it reaches gameCount.  I have tried a few different things that have all failed.  Here is a little snippet of the code.

```
int gameCount = [count intValue];
    int gameRows = 0;
    while (gameCount > gameRows) {
        gameRows++;
         NSString *thisUser = (NSString *) [dictionaryReturn objectForKey:@"away%i", gameRows];
```

This obviously does not work but I figured I was at least heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the purpose of the rest of the code, but at least this part should be writen this way:

```
...[dictionaryReturn objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"away%i", gameRows]]
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yea I wasn't very clear but your answer was perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually the only other thing is how can I make the pointer *thisUser increment like "away" does?

Comment: basically i just want to concatenate *thisUser and gameRows if possible

Comment: ond simple way to concat strings is [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %i", string1, string2, i]